# MS Word Customization can't find VSTO file

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, ms-word, clickonce, office-interop

I've developed a customization in Visual Studio for Word 2010 and have the solution saved in network share (using a UNC path) and the actual Word document is saved in a folder in SharePoint.

Everything works fine, users can open the document and use the customisation and when they've gone through the steps the add-on requires they click a button which saves the completed document to a different location in SharePoint.  Al good.  When you however now open the newly saved document from SharePoint I get the following error message:

> Cannot currently access the deployment manifest at this location:
>   "[URL to document path in SharePoint]".  You muyst set the deployment
>   manifest location to a UNC share or a local path when
>   ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.RunFromFolder is true.

Have done some searches on these terms but getting nothing useful!  Would appreciate any help you could offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem, need to give a bit more background to explain the issue a bit better.

I'm using a number of Action Panes to create a wizard-like experience for the user.  When the user hits "Next" on the first pane I have code (using `ThisDocument.SaveAs2`) so automatically do a Save As to a specific folder in SharePoint (actually the structure gets created on the fly before it being saved).

On the final pane when they hit Finish I was running the exact same code to Save As but to the exact same location and filename and this is what seems to have caused the problem.  The bottom line is that the custom property `_AssemblyLocation` was changed somehow in this process to only have the filename of the vsto file without an absolute path, so on re-opening the document it was looking for this file in same location.

By simply changing this to a Save instead of a Save As it now works perfectly.  Took me insane amounts of time to figure that out but my own fault!

Answer (score 1):

Try this article:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb772100(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb772100%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Particularly  the steps under the heading:
To put the document on a server that's running SharePoint

I don't think word trusts your document after you save it in a different location.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I finally found the problem, will document below to explain